# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'expm1'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I get strange mistake at the second line:

```
arr = np.array(generated_arr)
arr1 = np.expm1(arr)
```

**'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'expm1'**

The same mistake I get, when change `expm1` to `exp`

Some data to debug:

```
arr = np.array(generated_arr)
import pkg_resources
print pkg_resources.get_distribution("numpy").version
print np
print np.__class__
print arr.__class__
print arr.shape
print arr
```

The output:

```

```
1.11.0rc1
<module 'numpy' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>
<type 'module'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1579,)
[ array([[  1.39629781e+00,   4.14663363e+00,   5.04576588e+00, ...,
          4.14168171e-04,  -2.15612352e-04,   6.21061117e-05],
       [  4.37385142e-01,   3.90312672e+00,   4.62484837e+00, ...,
          3.31519928e-04,  -1.47391009e-04,  -9.80544501e-05],
       [  1.04018736e+00,   3.52265477e+00,   4.22140884e+00, ...,
          2.85610644e-04,  -2.27154887e-04,   1.22420461e-04],
       ..., 
       [  1.16933368e-01,   2.18587905e-01,   2.91605648e-02, ...,
         -2.51969323e-05,  -2.02958588e-04,   3.56372271e-04],
       [  6.13062084e-02,  -5.08567132e-02,   6.80716217e-01, ...,
          1.47589904e-04,  -2.29502155e-04,   2.23611612e-04],
       [  1.12629330e+00,   1.22596359e+00,   2.76913071e+00, ...,
          2.89709296e-05,  -1.83835567e-04,   2.72985526e-05]])
 array([  6.37278679e-01,   2.30754606e+00,   3.46814492e+00, ...,
        -1.51947506e-04,  -4.84544221e-04,  -9.77919355e-05])
 array([  6.78017229e-01,   2.63326503e+00,   3.52786812e+00, ...,
        -1.03349607e-03,  -1.79337033e-05,   6.34871024e-04])
 ...,
 array([  3.57849307e-01,   2.82791038e+00,   2.98997590e+00, ...,
         4.22304690e-04,  -3.08250013e-05,   3.39049988e-04])
 array([  3.33362706e-01,   2.81584996e+00,   3.01867798e+00, ...,
         4.95177795e-04,   1.33572024e-05,   4.13643392e-04])
 array([  3.24378797e-01,   2.79054058e+00,   3.04193415e+00, ...,
         5.40986023e-04,   5.98242713e-05,   4.79647799e-04])]
```

```

So does someone have any suggestions what is happening? Why I can't take exp of np.ndarray?

Comment: What is `generated_arr` (data type, size, etc)?  Also, in your output, include `arr.dtype`.  It looks like `arr` is an `object` array, and `np.expm1` doesn't know how to operate on generic python objects, so it tries to use the object's `expm1` method (and fails, because there isn't one).

Comment: Probably you have broken some links by inadvertance. Restart your session.

Comment: Your array is seriously messed up. You've done something wrong when building it; you need to fix whatever went wrong when you built it, and then `expm1` will work.

Comment: It looks like `arr` is an array of dtype `np.object` that contains a bunch of other numpy arrays. This will happen if you call `np.array` on a sequence of objects that can't be concatenated together into a single array with a homogeneous dtype. In your case the problem seems to be that `generated_arr` contains arrays with incompatible dimensions (the first one is two-dimensional, whereas the rest seem to be one-dimensional).